# Convert xml to csv and columns need to be in form of rows (pivot)

Tags: csv, xslt, xslt-1.0, transpose

I need to transform column data into row of xml using xslt and generate output in csv. Here is example xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Entry>
    <PERSON>12345</PERSON>
     <Emergency_Contacts_group>
         <ADDRESS_LINE_1>Solaris, dela rosa</ADDRESS_LINE_1>
         <ADDRESS_LINE_2>Solaris, dela rosa_2</ADDRESS_LINE_2>`enter code here`
         <ADDRESS_LINE_3>makati</ADDRESS_LINE_3>
         <ADDRESS_LINE_4>1229</ADDRESS_LINE_4>
    </Emergency_Contacts_group>
 </Report_Entry>
```

Expected output:

```
Person|Address_LINE_TYPE|ADDRESS_LINE_DATA
12345|ADDRESS_LINE_1|Solaris, dela rosa
12345|ADDRESS_LINE_2|Solaris,dela rosa_2
12345|ADDRESS_LINE_3|makati
12345|ADDRESS_LINE_4|1229
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Person|Address_LINE_TYPE| ADDRESS_LINE_DATA</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'ADDRESS_LINE')]">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../../PERSON"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMBS